# Integration with paypal redirect issue

Tags: django, paypal, django-oscar, openedx

I am integrating paypal with my openedx ironwood install.
To implement ecommerce capabilities - openedx ironwood uses django oscar shopping cart.

It works to the point where one can enter their credit card information and submit the form.

However after submitting the form the [following error occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODjt7.jpg)
and this is the corresponding address in the address bar:

https://http/payment/paypal/execute/?paymentId=PAYID-LZWTHVY60U970153W662623L&token=EC-45D081042G524235T&PayerID=UBRT2SFRKASXL

Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: What was the redirecting URL or IP of this error? is it PayPal URL or your instance URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the URL `https://http/payment/paypal/execute/` was given to PayPal as the return URL, and so it tried to return there after payment approval within the PayPal checkout.

You / the django oscar shopping cart needs to pass a valid return URL to PayPal in the API call at payment creation time.

Comment: It seems as though the return url is defined on the paypal developer platform as shown in the pic (follow the link) https://imgur.com/a/WpLn0YS

What would be an appropriate oauth return url?

Comment: oauth is not used for payment processing.  The return URL is not configured in developer.  It is set in the API call to create each payment. This happens at checkout time, after the cart is finalized for payment and before redirecting the payer to PayPal.